# Can't debug using breakpoints with Gradle in Intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber-java

I'm using Cucumber + Gradle in Intellij and can't figure out how to debug using breakpoints. I tried the suggestions posted by other users but none of them work for me. Has anyone figured out an easy way to do this? Below is my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + 
sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty',
                    '--plugin', 'json:build/reports/cucumber-report.json',
                    '--plugin', 'html:build/reports/cucumber-report.html',
                    '--glue', 'stepDefinitions',
                    'src/test/java']
            systemProperty "cucumber.options", 
System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
        systemProperty "url", System.properties.getProperty("url")
        systemProperty "environment", 
System.properties.getProperty("environment")
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What Run/Debug configuration do you use for debugging? E.g. you can use IDE's own [Run/Debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-cucumber-java.html) to debug [cucumber steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-cucumber-tests.html) without needing to configure options in build.gradle.

Comment: I tried that but my step definitions file isn't being recognized

Comment: Please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235582/2000323

Comment: Seems to be working now. I'm not exactly sure how but it works now