# Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.cli.Main

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, refactoring

While reworking a project in Intellij into modules, i came across this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" "-Dorg.jetbrains.run.directory=C:\Users\Ash\Documents\1_Code Stuff\Java\Udemy course\guru-pet-clinic" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=55768:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4\plugins\cucumber-java\lib\cucumber-jvmFormatter.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4\plugins\cucumber-java\lib\cucumber-jvmFormatter3.jar" cucumber.api.cli.Main --plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter "C:/Users/Ash/Documents/1_Code Stuff/Java/Udemy course/guru-pet-clinic"

Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.cli.Main
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I later found out that the Run configuration was wrong due to the refactoring and then defaulted, thus causing an error.

The way I fixed it was to **delete all configurations** (drop down in top right of image) and also **remove cucumber java** by selecting and clicking the "-"

Then I right clicked on the Main application i wanted to run and selected run, or ctrl + shift + F10 for the short cut.

[image]

Comment: The class cucumber.api.cli.Main is deprecated by now. You can use **io.cucumber.core.cli.main** instead.

Comment: I used io.cucumber.core.cli.main and also did the same suggested by the accepted answer. still it gives the same error. any other thing I can try ?

Comment: this one did not work for me either

Comment: should be  io.cucumber.core.cli.Main,  not  io.cucumber.core.cli.main  (Main with upper case)

Comment: Upper Case Main doesn't work too.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a solution.
By adding below dependency to pom.xml will clear above exception

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the question because it will resolve your problem ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it turned out that I opened as a project the parent directory of the actual main project directory. When I opened the correct project directory in IntelliJ, that had the "src" folder as a direct subfolder, cucumber worked.
For reference, see instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-cucumber-support-in-project.html#folder-structure, and a similar StackOverflow thread here: [Intellij IDEA Run configurations for Cucumber runner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224162/intellij-idea-run-configurations-for-cucumber-runner-class/47235582#47235582) .

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer of @kruemelnerd worked. Just the classname needs to be uppercase: `io.cucumber.core.cli.Main`

If you want to change this in general, open the link at the bottem left of the Run/Debug Configurations window: **"Edit configurations template..."**, select **Cucumber Java** and set the value **Main class** to `io.cucumber.core.cli.Main`.