# Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.cli.Main Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.cli.Main

Tags: java, cucumber

I am having issues running my .feature file in IntelliJ. Can someone help me step by step on how to fix the problems?[Open the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNH4b.jpg)

Comment: Have you already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948983/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-cucumber-cli-main)?

Comment: @AddeusExMachina Yes, i have checked that but still the same issue. Been  trying for 1 days