# Could not find or load main class cucumber.cli.Main -2

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

**Issue:**
I have been trying to run a test case using Gradle and cucumber. The same version of cucumber is working for my colleagues, but when I try to clone and trigger a test case, it is giving the error below.

**Output**

```
**Error :**Testing started at 3:33 PM ...

.
.
.
.
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.cli.Main
```

[image: Image of Feature File]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij IDEA Run configurations for Cucumber runner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224162/intellij-idea-run-configurations-for-cucumber-runner-class)

Comment: Thanks, but in the link, you provided I could see your feature files are defined using cucumber java plugin. I have it installed for my project, but my feature files are not able to use cucumber plugin. Please refer to the image.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and attach a small sample project to reproduce the issue. Also provide the logs: Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...